# Unity3D post a json to ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api

Tags: json, post, asp.net-web-api, unity-game-engine

How I do a post with json value to a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api Controller?
I tried it several ways, but I can't make it works.

First, my simplified Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public Interaction Post(Interaction filter)
{
     return filter;
}
```

And my post method with Unity3D WWW:

```
public string GetJson(string url, WWWForm form)
{
    var www = new WWW(url, form);

    while (!www.isDone) { };

    return www.text;
}
```

Where my WWWForm is:

```
var form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("filter", interaction);
```

I tried specify the header, like:

```
public string GetJson(string url, byte[] data)
{
    var header = new Hashtable();
    header.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");

    var www = new WWW(url, data, header);

    while (!www.isDone) { };

    return www.text;
}
```

I really tried to solve this by more than ten different ways and I always get the same result:

```
Debug.Log(input); // {"Id":15,"Name":"Teste","Description":"Teste","Value":0.0,"Time":10.0}
Debug.Log(output); // {"Id":0,"Name":null,"Description":null,"Value":0.0,"Time":0.0}
```

Any direction will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding this to your action `if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, this.ModelState));
            }` and see if you get any model state errors in response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use WWWForm to post JSON. Use something like this.

```
string input = "You JSON goes here";

Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

WWW www = new WWW("http://yourserver/path", body, headers);

yield www;

if(www.error) {
         Debug.Log(www.error);
}
else {
        Debug.Log(www.text);
}
```

Assuming JSON string in input is like this,

```
{"Id":15,"Name":"Teste","Description":"Teste","Value":0.0,"Time":10.0}
```

you will need a class like this

```
public class Interaction
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string Teste { get; set; }
   // other properties
}
```

for the action method like this to work

```
public Interaction Post(Interaction filter)
```

Comment: :It works! Thanks a lot. For everyone... Don't forget to configure the crossdomain file to accept these requests. See the [article](http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html)

Comment: Y i am getting error error CS0103: The name `Encoding' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Because you don't have a `using System.Text;` at the beginning if your file @Sona?