# How to pass Json array to WWWform as field in unity

Tags: arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I want to pass three field in `wwwform`, which contain two single value and a json array.

Here is my Json:

```
{
     "Fname":"Abc",
     "Lname":"Xyz",
     "Marks": [{"MarksA":"23","MarksB":"65" },
     {"MarksA":"24","MarksB":"56" } ]
   }
```

My current code is

```
 void Start()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("Fname", "Abc");
        form.AddField("Lname", "Xyz");
        //passing the array as string
        string Mymarks = "[{\"MarksA\":\"23\",\"MarksB\":\"65\" },{\"MarksA\":\"24\",\"MarksB\":\"56\" } ]";
        form.AddField("Marks", Mymarks);
        WWW www = new WWW("Urltoservice", form);
        StartCoroutine("PostRequest", www);
    }
    IEnumerator PostRequest(WWW www)
    {
        yield return www;
        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Session Saved");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);

        }
    }
```

But I am getting `500 internal server Error`. Please help me.

Comment: The fact that you are getting a response means this code works. Your server code - does not. It either expects different input or has unrelated problem. Please post server side code.

Comment: I am able to send data to the server with fiddler that is working fine.If i pass two fields it also works the third field is inserted as null

Comment: Change your server code to `print_r($_POST); die();` (or equivalent in your server language) and look at the differences what fiddler sees as output and what unity sees.  In Unity, to see server output, put `print(www.text);` in place of `Debug.Log("Session Saved");` I suspect fiddler passes something differently than Unity.

Comment: The only problem i am facing is when i pass an array of objects and there is no problem when i pass simple object, in that object there is one to many relationship that i am passing, if i am passing only parent object it works fine but when i pass related child collection with parent i get error for instance     {
     "Fname":"Abc",
     "Lname":"Xyz",
     "Marks": [{"MarksA":"23","MarksB":"65" },
     {"MarksA":"24","MarksB":"56" } ]
   }  in this data if i donot pass marks value it works fine in unity but when i pass complete data i get error 500 internal server error

Comment: i have also checked with fiddler it works fine and returnning the id what i needed but in unity i get error, it is not printing print(www.text); because of false condition

Comment: the actual problem is when i am passing the json array string to wwwform and pass that wwwform in to www object then www class has property called data which encode the wwwform data to url-encoding, and in my case it encodes the symbols used in json array (" [ { } ] " ) in to %22, %5d etc that is why i am getting that error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910788/unity3d-post-a-json-to-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api.                                                                                       This is the way to do it. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try using WWW instead of WWWForm

```
    using UnityEngine;

    using UnityEngine.UI;

    using System.Collections;

    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class SendData : MonoBehaviour {

     void Start()
     {
         gameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(SendOnClick);
     }
     IEnumerator WaitForWWW(WWW www)
     {
         yield return www;


         string txt = "";
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
             txt = www.text;  //text of success
         else
             txt = www.error;  //error
         GameObject.Find("TextDemo").GetComponent<Text>().text =  "--------\n\n" + txt;
     }
     void SendOnClick()
     {
         try
         {
             GameObject.Find("TextDemo").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Starting..";   
             string ourPostData = "{\"MarksA\":\"23\",\"MarksB\":\"65\" },{\"MarksA\":\"24\",\"MarksB\":\"56\" }";
             Dictionary<string,string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
             headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
             byte[] jData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ourPostData.ToCharArray());
             WWW api = new WWW("YOUR URL", jData, headers);
             StartCoroutine(WaitForWWW(api));
         }
         catch (UnityException ex) { Debug.Log(ex.message); }
     }

    }
```