# POST parameter is always null only in Unity3d

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api

I have this code on the asp.net web api2 server:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult Login(RequestLogin args)
    {
        //work
    }
```

I trying send post request from "**advanced REST client**" with parameters:

```
http://localhost:54382/api/Home/Login
application/json
{"Name":"asd","DeviceId":"818cd41169410e6f20ef55b2917d0e15e5cf072f"}
```

...and it work perfect! args in Login method is **full**.

But
If i try this from **Unity3d**:

```
UnityWebRequest www;
var url = http://localhost:54382/api/Home/Login;
string jsonObj = JsonUtility.ToJson(request.args);
Debug.Log(jsonObj); //{"Name":"asd","DeviceId":"818cd41169410e6f20ef55b2917d0e15e5cf072f"}
www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, jsonObj);
www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
yield return www.Send();
```

args in Login method contain **null** values.

```
[Serializable]
    public class RequestLogin
    {
        public string Name;
        public string DeviceId;
    }
```

I break my head for several days. Help me please

Comment: Are you talking about Unity 3D game engine or Unity Dependency Injection? Sorry to ask this question, but you are incorrectly referencing the DI package.

Comment: Unity3d game engine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was experiencing exactly the same issue after upgrading Unity to version 2017.3.0. The fix that worked for me was to set UnityWebRequest.chunkedTransfer to false.
My post method looks like this:

```
public static UnityWebRequest PostJson(string url, string json)
    {
        UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest(url, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST);
        byte[] bodyRaw = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(json);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.chunkedTransfer = false;
        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, same. I believe this is the root cause. https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/www-request-fails-to-get-content-length-header

Comment: In my case `chunkedTransfer=false` did not help, but parsing Json body to byte array and using upload and download handlers did the trick! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html), it seems like you have the option to do it like so:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("Name", "asd");
form.AddField("DeviceId", "818cd41169410e6f20ef55b2917d0e15e5cf072f");

www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
```

Can you try it as the documentation implies?

Comment: Doing a quick search I found this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1068919/unet-receiving-null-string-values-in-message.html

Do you also share the RequestLogin in both assemblies?

Comment: i have shared dll with entities. Put in to Unity Plugins and add to web api project

Comment: Can you try separating them as it's mentioned in the link above, and try it again. Actually It's surprising that the WWWForm didn't work, since it shouldn't depend on the shared class.

Comment: Also tried WWWForm and it did not work.  Only @Gion solution worked for me. Does anyone have managed to make WWWForm work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem by returning from "UnityWebRequest" to the old "WWW" method.
Example:
[Unity3D post a json to ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910788/unity3d-post-a-json-to-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api)